# How do you isolate the digits following a decimal in R?

Tags: r, decimal, digit, isolation, truncated

For example: I have the number 123.456 and want to return 456.

The function `trunc()` basically isolates ([truncates](http://127.0.0.1:19420/library/base/html/Round.html)) the numbers *before* the decimal.

**Is there a function to isolate just the digits *after* the decimal?**

Two follow-up questions:

1. Is there a way to do this without writing out the regex?
2. What if I want to maintain the sign? For example, if I wanted to (reverse) truncate -123.456 to -456.

Comment: `sign(x) * (abs(x) %% 1)`

Comment: @Gregor wouldn't that be `x-trunc(x)`?

Comment: Ooops, missed that an integer is wanted. Seems like floating point arithmetic issues waiting to mess you up. Nice that many answers are taking care of that, but leaving it as a decimal seems safer.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What would be a use case for this?

Comment: @Roland, well really I only need it to test the presence of non whole-number integers. I was interested in how to extend that concept a bit further mostly out of curiosity. But, then I figured I couldn't come up with sleek ways to do as the question asks, so I asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the modulo operator (%%) with 1 as the devisor works I guess. It does successfully isolate the numbers following the decimal, but leaves the decimal:

```
123.456 %% 1
[1] 0.456
```

However it only works for positive numbers in that the sign is not preserved nor are the proper numbers reported (b/c of modulo operator's functionality):

```
-123.456 %% 1
[1] 0.544  #not what is wanted
```

Including `abs()` fixes that issue, but doesn't help report sign. Sign could be included by adding:

```
sign(x) * (abs(x) %% 1)
```

---

If we really wanted to report *just* the digits after the decimal (i.e., *excluding the 0 and the decimal*), we could do the following (presented in 2 steps for clarity):

```
x <- -123.456
y <- sign(x) * (abs(x) %% 1)
as.numeric(gsub("0.","",y))
[1] -456  #as desired from part 2 in the OP
```

Comment: We could easily turn this into a FUNCTION that allows you to choose whether to include the sign in the output or not. I'll call the function "decIso" for decimal isolator:  `decIso <- function(x, sign = TRUE) {
  y <- (abs(x) %% 1) ;
  z <- ifelse(sign == T, sign(x) * y, y) ;
  as.numeric(gsub("0.","",z))
}`

Answer (score 4):

I don't like text processing for these kinds of operations.

The tricky part is converting the fractional number into the integer. Here I use a loop. It's unlikely that many iterations are needed. So, performance is probably not an issue.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  y <- abs(x) - floor(abs(x))

  n <- 0
  while (abs(y - round(y, n)) > .Machine$double.eps^0.5) {
    n <- n + 1
  }

  sign(x) * y * 10^n
}

fun(123.456)
#[1] 456
fun(-123.456)
#[1] -456
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to go

```
> x <- c(123.456, -123.456)
> sign(x) * as.integer(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\."), "[", 2))
[1]  456 -456
```